# How to avoid the alphabetical order for storing elements in dictionary in scrapy python

Tags: python, json, scrapy, dictionary

I am working on scrapy, i fetched some items from website and storing them in json files.

My `items.py` code is :

```
job_title = Field()
full_or_part_Time = Field()
location_affiliates = Field()
department = Field()
requisition_number = Field()
```

Actually after fetching , the items stored in the json file are in the following format

```
{"full_or_part_Time": ["Full Time"], 
 "department": ["808 - Spons Prj Accounting"], 
 "requisition_number": ["12-1407456"], 
 "job_title": ["Accountant"], 
 "location_affiliates": ["Mount Sinai Medical Center (Manhattan)"]}
```

But i want to save the items in the format i declared in the `items.py` file.
Can anyone please let me know how to arrange in the declared format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON objects are not meant to be ordered.

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

[JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for wanting to order the keys, even if the order is not semantically significant.  For example, you might want to put the "name" key at the top of each object so it's easier to read -- for humans.